# writing .java files from vim hangs

Tags: vim, vi

Whenever I write .java files from vim, the write operation seems to cause some kind of hang up.  It successfully writes the file, with a message like

```
"path/file.java" 123L, 456C written"
```

but then never returns the cursor to me.  If I hit Ctrl+C, it will return the cursor... after several more seconds.

I can't figure out why this is happening.  This only seems to happen with Java.  I haven't experienced this issue when writing, for example, python, bash, text files, html.  Any vim experts have ideas?

Here is my .vimrc for reference:

```
set number
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
syntax on

set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=10
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=1


set nocompatible              " be iMproved
filetype off                  " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" " required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Bundle 'klen/python-mode'
Bundle 'honza/dockerfile.vim'
Bundle 'SirVer/ultisnips'

filetype plugin indent on     " required!

let g:pymode_folding = 0
let g:pymode_lint_ignore = "W391"
let g:pymode_lint = 0
let g:pymode_lint_cwindow = 0
let g:pymode_run = 0

let g:pymode_rope_lookup_project = 1
let g:pymode_rope_goto_definition_bind = ''
let g:pymode_rope_goto_definition_cmd = 'e'

let python_highlight_all = 1

" Flake8 setup and shortcut
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8']
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=W391'


" Set html, coffee, and javascript indent depths to 2-space.
autocmd FileType coffee,htm,html,xhtml,xml,php,javascript,mako setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2

" If you prefer the Omni-Completion tip window to close when a selection is
" made, these lines close it on movement in insert mode or when leaving
" insert mode
autocmd CursorMovedI * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable any of the plugins?

Comment: My guess would be syntactic. (Since that activates on saves, not sure about the rest of the plugins). You should also look into updating the Vundle syntax.

Comment: When I tried disabling plugins, checked behavior, and then retried enabling syntastic, it becomes clear that the issue is with syntastic.  Thanks for the help.  I guess I'll have to see if there are any better/faster vim java linters, or make sytax checking passive on java files.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem. It was because the syntastic plugin.

Adding this line in my vimrc solved my problem.

```
let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['\.java$']
```

well then the plugin will not check syntax for `.java` files.

Comment: That would prevent syntastic from ever checking Java files, which is probably not what you want.  A better solution is to turn on passive mode for Java files: `let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active', 'passive_filetypes': ['java'] }`.  This way Java files are checked only when you run `:SyntasticCheck` explicitly.